# getJSON Loop Until Response

Tags: php, jquery, json, loops, getjson

I have a PHP process which updates files, and writes a status report with each file.

While that is happening, I was hoping to update the user's browser until the final response.

Unless there is a better way, I simply wanted some advice on how to loop infinitely refreshing `getJSON()` results until the ajax response comes.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You might be interested in server-sent events (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp).

Comment: You can just keep processing on the PHP side, and emitting a bit more HTML. (Treat it like a line-printer). The browser will keep rendering & waiting for more, as long as you send something at least occasionally. Then close the `</BODY></HTML>` when you're finally finished.

Comment: I don't know that there is a "best" way to do this with the level of detail given.  I've seen many ways to do this kind of thing. Just look at any HTTP implementation of a chat system. More modern examples might use Websockets (or SignalR in the IIS/ASP.NET world).

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being the solution I used:

```
$(document).on('click', "#ss_batch_edit_processing", function (e) { 

    var ids = get_selected();
    var status_location = '<?php echo symbiostock_TMPDIR . '/report.txt' ?>';

    if(ids == 0){
        return;
        }       

    $('.' + loading_icon_small).show();

    var data = {
        action: 'ss_professional_ajax',
        security: '<?php echo $ajax_nonce; ?>',
        reprocessing_action: $('input:radio[name=ss_reprocessing_action]:checked').val(),
        ids: ids,                  
    };      

    var completed = 0;

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) { 

        $('.' + loading_icon_small).hide(); 

        completed = 1;      

    });

    var get_update = function(){    

        $.getJSON(status_location, function (data) {                
            var update = '<ul><li><strong>'+data['title']+'</strong></li><li><strong>Count:</strong> '+data['count']+' / '+data['total']+'</li><li><strong>Last processed</strong>: Image # '+data['last_id']+'</li></ul>';
            $('#ss-reprocessing-results').html(update).delay(1000);         
        });

        if(completed == 1){
            clearInterval(timed_requests)
            return false;
        }   

    };      

    var interval = 1000; // every 1 second      
    var timed_requests = setInterval(get_update, interval);         
});
```